# How to iterate over s3 bucket to collect all keys from a given date of a subfolder-boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, aws-cli, boto

I am trying to iterate over the files in my s3 bucket and send all the files(or keys) that run time were in 2019, 2018, or 2017 to a csv file.

The structure of my s3 path goes like this:

```
file/archive/run=2017-10-07-06-13-21/folder_paths/version=1-0-0/part-00000-b.txt
```

Inside the archive folder, there's sub-folder with numerous folder. Like this:

```
run=2017-10-06-06-13-21
run=2018-10-07-09-13-21
run=2019-10-07-07-13-23
run=2019-10-05-06-13-21
```

and so forth......

So basically, if the run= folder is in 2019, then send all the keys that  are in 2019 to a csv file, and all the keys that are in 2017 in anothewr csv file, and then all the files in 2018 in another csv file.

I started the code like this:

```
#Import boto3 module
import boto3
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

#This is to List existing Buckets for the AWS account

#Set key variables
PREFIX = 'shredded/'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
    )

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Bucket='my_bucket',Prefix=PREFIX):
        if 'run=2019' in obj.key:
            print('{0}:{1}'.format(bucket.name, obj.key))
```

The out put are all the files path as normal. I want to only output the files that run= time is in 2019, 2018, 2017.

Any suggestions would help.Thanks

Comment: if the object names match when they were uploaded it would be easier for you to filter based on last modified attribute of the object

Comment: Ok, do you know how to collect the last modified date and categorize by that?

Comment: well first off, is there a reason you are iterating over all your buckets if all the files are located in a single bucket?

Comment: True, i changed that.

Comment: I meant this line --> `for bucket in s3.buckets.all()` you are still iterating over all buckets

Comment: Do you know how to write it without that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206017/discussion-between-coder123-and-aws-apprentice).